# pyinstaller exe file wrong path

Tags: path, zip, pyinstaller, exe

it works when I run it not compiled but when it's a exe file it gives me the wrong path. something like this:
`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI36682\base_library.zip\os.pyc\file.zip`

pyinstaller flags:
`py -m PyInstaller -F .\downloader.py`

It saved the zip file in the correct path but the current_path is wrong so it cant find it

```py
import wget
import zipfile
import os

url = 'https://example.com/file.zip'
filename = wget.download(url)
current_path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
path =current_path+'\\'+filename
print(path)
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(current_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

os.startfile(current_path+'\\main.exe')
```